# web transition works but not in the i want it to

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have just added a up arrow to my footer & linked it to #top tag before my nav tag which works, sort of.

1 the transition on the up arrow works apart from it doesn't just play the transition when I move my mouse over it, it also plays the transition if my mouse is horizontally in line with it.

2 and i cant figure out how to get the scrollTop to show my nav as well, as it just scrolls to the bottom of the fixed header.

here is the code I am using :

```
<script>

        $(function() {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.substr(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top-300
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

css

```
.stage {
position:relative;
height: 8em;
}

.arrow {
position: absolute;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
top: 2em;
width: 100px; /* width of arrow */
-webkit-transition: .4s top;
-moz-transition: .4s top;
-o-transition: .4s top;
transition: .4s top;
}

.stage:hover .arrow {
left: 0;
top: 0;
}

#outer { 
position: relative; 
width: 100px; 
height: 100px; 
margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

php

```
<div id="wrapper"><!-- #### WRAPPER #### -->

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>><!-- #### HTML #### -->

<head><!-- #### HEAD #### -->

    <title><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></title><!-- #### TITLE #### -->

    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico">
    <link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>" rel="stylesheet">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>

    <!-- #### SCRIPT #### -->

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script>

        $(function() {
            $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
                var target = $(this.hash);
                target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.substr(1) +']');
                if (target.length) {
                    $('html,body').animate({
                        scrollTop: target.offset().top-300
                    }, 1000);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        });

    </script>

    <!-- #### / SCRIPT #### -->  

</head><!-- #### / HEAD #### -->

<body <?php body_class(); ?>><!-- #### BODY #### -->

    <header class="align_Center"><!-- #### HEADER #### -->

        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/logo/icon.Black.png" width="128px" height="128" style="padding: 20px">

        <br>

        <div class="align_Center" style="font-size:2em; color: #000;"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></div>

        <br>

        <div class="align_Center" style="font-size:1.2em; color: #000;"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>

    </header><!-- #### / HEADER #### --> 
<div class="_top" id="top"></div>
    <div id="nav"><!-- #### NAV #### -->

        <table class="main-nav" align="center">

            <tr>

                <td>

                    <?php

                        $args = array(
                        'theme_location' => 'primary',
                        'walker' => new Walker_Menu

                        );

                        wp_nav_menu( $args );

                    ?>

                </td>

            </tr>

        </table>

    </div><!-- #### / NAV #### -->

    <div class="content"><!-- #### CONTENT #### -->

        <div class="container"><!-- #### CONTAINER #### -->

            <br>



            <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebarRandom"><!-- #### COLUMN #### -->

                <p class="f_header">Random Movies</p>

                <?php

                    $args = array(

                        'post_status'       => 'publish',
                        'post_type'         => 'movies',
                        'posts_per_page'    => 25,
                        'orderby'           => 'rand'

                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ($query->have_posts()) {

                ?>

                <table width="100%"><!-- #### TABLE #### -->

                    <?php

                        while ($query->have_posts()) {

                            $query->the_post();

                    ?>

                    <tr>

                        <td class="movie_genre">    

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <?php

                        }

                    ?>

                </table><!-- #### / TABLE #### -->

                <?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </div><!-- #### / COLUMN #### -->

            <div class="col-md-6"><!-- #### COLUMN #### -->

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                <div class="panel panel-blue panel-body">

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() ); ?>

                </div>

                <?php endwhile;

                    else : echo '<p>NO CONTENT FOUND</p>';

                    endif;

                ?>

                <div style="border-bottom:1em"></div>

            </div><!-- #### / COLUMN #### -->

            <div class="col-md-3" id="sidebarYear"><!-- #### COLUMN #### -->

                <p class="f_header">Movies <?php echo date( 'Y' ); ?></p>

                <?php         

                    $args = array(

                        'post_status'       => 'publish',
                        'post_type'         => 'movies',
                        'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
                        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
                        'meta_query'        => array(
                            array(
                            'key'           => 'released',
                            'value'         => array( date( 'Y' ), date( 'Y' ) + 1 ),
                            'compare'       => 'BETWEEN'

                                ),

                            ),

                    );

                    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

                    if ($query->have_posts()) {

                ?>

                <table width="100%">

                    <?php

                        while ($query->have_posts()) {

                            $query->the_post();

                    ?>

                    <tr>

                        <td class="movie_genre">

                            <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

                        </td>

                    </tr>

                    <?php

                        }

                    ?>

                </table>

                <?php }; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

            </div><!-- #### / COLUMN #### -->

        </div><!-- / CONTAINER -->

        <br>

    </div><!-- #### / CONTENT #### -->

    <div id="footer"><!-- #### FOOTER #### -->
            <div class="outer">
        <div class="stage">

            <a href="#top">

                <img class="arrow" alt="" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/arrows/button_up_hover.png">

            </a>

                </div></div>

        <div class="align_Center" style="font-size:2em; color: #000;"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></div>

        <div class="align_Center" style="font-size:1.2em; color: #000; padding-bottom: 20px;">&copy;&nbsp;<?php bloginfo('name'); ?>&nbsp;<?php echo date('Y'); ?></div>

    </div><!-- #### / FOOTER #### -->

    <?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body><!-- #### BODY #### -->

</html><!-- #### HTML #### -->
```

Comment: A jsfiddle would be handy.

Comment: I'm sorry I have a account but cant figure the code out sorry

Comment: it doent need account for fiddle. you can go to this URL (https://jsfiddle.net/) and paste html,css and js in mentioned boxes. it will show result. but please remove php first and put normal html content.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/scottiescotsman/bxf24cnc/15/

Comment: it does the transition outside and horizontally with the img, but I just want it to do it on the img plz